# How to print toggle switch status to console

Tags: c#, blend

I'm trying to call action depending on toggle switch status. The following code throw the errors, that neither `Debug` nor `Console` does exist in this context.

```
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page {
    public MainPage() {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void ToggleNamePrivacy_Toggled(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e){
        if (toggleSwitch.IsOn == true){
            Debug.Print("On");
        }
        else{
            Console.WriteLine("Off");
        }
    }

}
```

Help is very appreciated.

Comment: What `Debug` are you trying to print to? Which `Console` are you trying to Write to? This looks like a UI application, not a Console application, thus there is probably no Console to write to.

Comment: I come from swift/ios and want to write the switch status a "debugger console" to first test, if the switch does what I want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use
`using System.Diagnostics;` to be allowed to use `Debug`

You can't use `Console` anywhere else console applications

Comment: this seems to be working. can you please tell me, where do I see the debug output?

Comment: @DavidSeek in `Output` window in Visual Studio

Comment: Okay, but even `Debug.WriteLine("TestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTest");`does not write anything on the output

Comment: Okay. I got it. Thank you